# how i can show the image in middle of div i want using CSS

Tags: html, css

i have a div who have some image inside them. i need to show them in center align means if i normally put that they align left.

the image is dynamic maybe it's small or big. i need to show them in middle in every condition.

how i can do this using css. any trick to do this

Comment: Is the image a background image or and `img` tag

Comment: Do you want the image to be center in horizontal and vertical alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
img {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-EN">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #container {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  img {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display: block;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img  src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" alt=" " />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway, you have to try it in all the browsers, I'm not sure if it works in all of them.

Centering stuff in HTML with CSS is one of the most painful things.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying the style `text-align: center` to the `div`.

Comment: it's not worked because i not define the width in image and i need them in middle.

Answer (score 0):

I you need the image to be at the horizontal center you can use the `text-align: center` on the `div` container as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HTTUa/)

But if you need the image to be horizontal and vertical center then it will be easy to do as given [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HTTUa/1/) using the background style property